# EF6 C# Join Not getting what expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables, one is called profiles and the other is called tools.
They are joined in a 1-many condition. i.e. a profile can have multiple tools and are joined that tools has a column which has the profile id.

Using C# i would like to have the a list of profiles which within the list there is also a list of the tools that are joined to that profile.

List(Of Profiles)

---List(Of tools) which is a child list of profiles.

I am using the following code:

```
var _profiles = _ve.tbl_profiles
                .Join(_ve.tbl_tools,
                    _p => _p.clm_profile_id,
                    _t => _t.clm_tool_profile_id,
                    (_p, _t) => new { _p, _t })
                .OrderBy(i =>i._p.clm_profile_name).ToList();
```

The testing data that i have is i have 2 profiles, 1 of which has just 1 tool and the other has 2 tools.

I am getting a list of tools only.
How can i change the code so that i have the data as i want it. It seems i am near but there is something i am not seeing

Comment: You should use navigation properties. There is no need for a manual join.

Comment: Your profile class should have a property `public virtual ICollection<Tool> Tools { get; set; }`. Then you could do `_context.Profiles.Include(p => p.Tools).OrderBy(p =>p.Name)`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thanks... that was very simple. Sometimes you overshadow simple things. I am going to add it as an answer with your mention!

Comment: @Oliver thanks also for your reply. The context is auto-generated as it is a model generated from an existing database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alexander Petrov mentioned in the comments. It can be simply accessed using simple navigation of the properties as it is already joined from the DB there is no need to do a manual join.

So to get the data from the table use:

```
 List<tbl_profiles> _profiles = _ve.tbl_profiles.OrderBy(i =>i.clm_profile_name).ToList();
```

And then iterate or any other operation needed by going through:

```
_profiles.tbl_tools ...
```

Thanks to @Alexander Petrov again!
Hope this helps anyone

Comment: Note that this would trigger lazy loading on the Tools references. To load the profiles with their tools use `_ve.tbl_profiles.Include(x => x.tbl_tools)....` to eager load them in one query. Be wary of the total amount of data being loaded though, this will be fine for smaller tables with a small number of `Includes` but can still lead to performance issues in larger, complex sets.